# Jquery click event on <a> tag not firing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, click

I'm trying to catch the jquery click event on an  tag with a class, but its not firing.

HTML: (there's 10 blocks)

```
<div id="block1">
   <div class="slideshow">
      <a class="popup" href="#imgform">
       <img src="<?php echo 'core/controllers/foto.php?o=1'; ?>" title="1" width="271px" height="413px">
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="block2">
   <div class="slideshow">
      <a class="popup" href="#imgform">
       <img src="<?php echo 'core/controllers/foto.php?o=2'; ?>" title="2" width="200px" height="129px">
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $popup = $('a.popup');
    $popup.live('click',function(){
        var id = $popup.parent().parent().attr('id');
        id = id.substring(5);
        alert(id);
        $.get('index.php?o='+id, function(data) {
            $popup.fancybox({
                //do stuff
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The alert is always returning 1 for some reason.

Comment: `live()` is deprecated. Use `on`

Comment: Why do you bind the click event to _document_ and not your links?

Comment: @DaniP. ye that was a typo of when i was trying to use .on

Comment: Also, IMHO you shouldn't use $ with variable names. This is not PHP.

Comment: You should only use `$` as the start of a variable name if it's going to be used as a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('a.popup').on('click',function(){
  alert($(this).parent().parent().attr('id')); // to check whether it is firing....
});
```

Comment: The `popup` class anchors don't have `id` attributes, so what does this accomplish?

Comment: This is returning the id it should I don't really see what I was doing wrong

Comment: Your original `var $popup = $('a.popup');` is an array of two elements and when you use it without index it always uses first element in `var id = $popup.parent().parent().attr('id');`. Try changin this line to `var id = this.parent().parent().attr('id');`

Answer (score 2):

This may help you.

1. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as of jQuery 1.7.
2. Make use of the `data` parameter in your AJAX calls this may ensure proper escaping of the query parameters. If you still insist doing it manually you can use [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).
3. In your specific case you can cache lot of things. Although, this may not work for dynamically added elements after loading is complete.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.popup').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.parent().parent().attr('id').substring(5);
        $this.click(function() {
            $.get('index.php', {
                o: id
            }, function(data) {
                $popup.fancybox({
                    //do stuff
                });
            });
        });
    });
});​
```

---

Moreover, using `data-*` attributes you can easily drop the `id` attribute parsing and have a cleaner markup.

1. Using a `block` classname.
2. Adding a `data-block-id` attribute.
3. You should definitely be using classnames to style elements and not IDs.

```
<div class="block" data-block-id="1">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <a class="popup" href="#imgform">
      <img src="<?php echo 'core/controllers/foto.php?o=1'; ?>" title="1" width="271px" height="413px">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.popup').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.parent().parent().data("block-id");
        $this.click(function() {
            $.get('index.php', {
                o: id
            }, function(data) {
                $popup.fancybox({
                    //do stuff
                });
            });
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very sexy

Comment: Problem is that in my css I style every block differently

Comment: @R4VANG3R, you should use classnames to style and not IDs e.g. `<div class="block red"/>` vs `<div class="block blue"/>`. If you don't want to then the first alternative it is what you want (although, not recommended.) Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

use `this`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.popup').on('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        id = id.substring(5);
        alert(id);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to bind the click callback to your links. You'll also probably want to prevent the default behaviour, otherwise your page will reload.

```
$(".popup").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id')[5];
    alert(id);
});​
```

Also, using classes effectively could cut out most of those `parent` calls, before they get out of hand. For example.

```
<!-- Make the head div belong to class "head" -->
<div id="block1" class="head">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <a class="popup" href="#imgform">

$(".popup").click(function(){
    // If you click the first link, you'll get "block1" in the alert.
    var id = $(this).parents(".head").attr('id');
    alert(id);
});​
```

Comment: When I try this I get
Error: Unable to get property '5' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @R4VANG3R - Yeah I made the changes, it should alert `1` when you click on the first image.

Comment: I guess you need : var $id = $(this).parents("div").eq(1).attr("id");

Comment: @AkhilSekharan - You could avoid it by using classes and attributes effectively.

Comment: Yes. I commented that for your last answer. sorry. connection slow.

Comment: @AkhilSekharan - No problem :) I put an example in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In you event handler, you need to use the event that was actually clicked.

```
$('a.popup').click(function() {
  var $id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
  ...
});
```

Please note that as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() or .click() to attach event handlers.

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Should be using `on` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $popup = $('a.popup');
    $popup.live('click',function(){ 
        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.closest('[id^="block"]').attr('id');
        id = id.substring(5);
        alert(id);
        $.get('index.php?o='+id, function(data) {
            element.fancybox({
                //do stuff
            });
        });
    });
});
```

If you are on jQuery 1.7 +, Use:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'a.popup' ,function(){ 
        //do Stuff
    });
```

Comment: For the nth time this question, `live` is deprecated, and you should use `on`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem where i wasnt able to get i click I tried on() its better than live().

Check this link for more http://api.jquery.com/on/ In this page check out the last three examples at the end of the page you might get a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(document).on("click", "$popup", function() {
var id = $popup.parent().parent().attr('id');
        id = id.substring(5);
        alert(id);
        $.get('index.php?o='+id, function(data) {
            $popup.fancybox({
                //do stuff
            });

});
```